# Order the parent and child row in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We want to order the parent child rows as below:-

Input:-

```
Child | Parent |
YA011 | YA010 | 
YA012 | YA010 |
YA022 | YA020 |
YA030 | YA020 |
YA021 | YA020 |
YA190 | YA000 |
YA200 | YA190 |
YA010 | YA200 |
YA020 | YA200 |
```

Excepted output:-

```
Child | Parent | 
YA011 | YA010 |              1st child of YA010
YA012 | YA010 |              2nd child of YA010
YA010 | YA200 |.             Then YA010
YA021 | YA020 |              1st child of YA020
YA022 | YA020 |              2nd child of YA020
YA030 | YA020 |              3rd child of YA020
YA020 | YA200 |              Then YA020
YA200 | YA190 |              Then parent of YA010 and YA020 i.e., YA200
YA190 | YA000 |              Then parent of YA200 i.e, YA190
```

we has written below query for this:-

```
WITH RECURSIVE generation AS (
  SELECT child, parent, [parent] parents, 0 as level FROM temp2
   UNION ALL
  SELECT g.child, t.parent, parents || [t.parent] , level +1 as level
    FROM generation g
    JOIN temp2 t ON g.parent = t.child AND level <=9
), temp as (
SELECT child, ARRAY_REVERSE(parents)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] parent, level
  FROM generation
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY child ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(parents) DESC) = 1 ) 
select * from temp
Order by level, child
```

but we are getting below result:-

```
Row     Child | Parent | level
1.         YA011 | YA010 | 0
2.         YA012 | YA010 | 0
3.         YA021 | YA020 | 0
4.         YA022 | YA020 | 0
5.         YA030 | YA020 | 0
6.         YA010 | YA200 | 1
7.         YA020 | YA200 | 1
8.         YA200 | YA190 | 2
9.         YA190 | YA000 | 3
```

If you see in the above output the row 6 should be after row 2 as YA010 is the parent of YA011 and YA012.

Can anyone please redirect us with the right approach to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your sample data. Running these will return to YA000.

For easy data insert, I renamed your values from YA... to YA**9**... .

The ordering you asked is called **Post-order traversal visits** of a tree. This can be archived by creating a full path name for each entry and sort them ascending. I consider only the first 10 characters of the name. Missing characters or no further children is filled with "z", considered to be the last character in use. Please see the `TEMP function` for this task.

`(( SELECT ))` runs a query and unnests the names and transforms them.

```sql
create temp function format_my_string(s string) as (concat(substring("zzzzzzzzzz",1+length(s),10),substring(s,1,10)));


with RECURSIVE tbl as ( 
Select  9011 Child , 9010 parent , 
union all select    9012 , 9010 ,
union all select    9022 , 9020 ,
union all select    9030 , 9020 ,
union all select    9021 , 9020 ,
union all select    9190 , 9000 ,
union all select    9200 , 9190 ,
union all select    9010 , 9200 ,
union all select    9020 , 9200 ,
),
temp2 as (select 'YA'||child child, 'YA'||parent parent from tbl)
,  generation AS (
  SELECT child, parent, [parent] parents, 0 as level FROM temp2
   UNION ALL
  SELECT g.child, t.parent, parents || [t.parent] , level +1 as level
    FROM generation g
    JOIN temp2 t ON g.parent = t.child AND level <=9
), temp as (
SELECT child, ARRAY_REVERSE(parents)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] parent, level, concat(array_to_string(ARRAY_REVERSE(parents),"->"),"-->",child) as info,
((Select string_Agg(format_my_string(parents_)) from unnest(ARRAY_REVERSE(parents)||[child,"","","","","","","","","","","",""]) parents_)) as sorting
  FROM generation
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY child ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(parents) DESC) = 1 ) 
select * from temp
Order by sorting  #level, child
```